# Mongo DB search Query not giving results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```js
db.feedback.find({
  "$or":[
    {"template_id":{"$regex":".*22532.*","$options":"i"}},
    {"user_id":{"$regex":".*22532.*","$options":"i"}}
  ]
})
```

`template_id` is a string and `user_id` is NumberLong data type and It's not finding a result. Its giving result for `template_id` if I put a correct value, only user_id column seems not responding, Any thoughts?

Sample Data

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ef21b7de21f8756b67da6e7"), "action_monkey" : 0, "feedback" : false, "more_feedback" : 0, "template_id" : "M23G5RK", "user_id" : 23423 }, /* 2 createdAt:6/15/2020, 3:16:53 PM*/ { "_id" : ObjectId("5ee74a95ae8ac276076db26a"), "action_monkey" : 0, "feedback" : false, "more_feedback" : 0, "template_id" : "M23G5RK", "user_id" : 23375 }, /* 3 createdAt:6/15/2020, 5:55:22 AM*/ { "_id" : ObjectId("5ee6c6faae8ac276076db24b"), "action_monkey" : 0, "feedback" : false, "more_feedback" : 0, "template_id" : "M23G5RK", "user_id" : 23423 }
```

Comment: Hey @ovais could you please add few sample data

Comment: {
 "_id" : ObjectId("5ef21b7de21f8756b67da6e7"),
 "action_monkey" : 0,
 "feedback" : false,
 "more_feedback" : 0,
 "template_id" : "M23G5RK",
 "user_id" : 23423
},

/* 2 createdAt:6/15/2020, 3:16:53 PM*/
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5ee74a95ae8ac276076db26a"),
 "action_monkey" : 0,
 "feedback" : false,
 "more_feedback" : 0,
 "template_id" : "M23G5RK",
 "user_id" : 23375
},

/* 3 createdAt:6/15/2020, 5:55:22 AM*/
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5ee6c6faae8ac276076db24b"),
 "action_monkey" : 0,
 "feedback" : false,
 "more_feedback" : 0,
 "template_id" : "M23G5RK",
 "user_id" : 23423
},

Comment: Regex operates on string, not number.  Since the type of the field in the documents doesn't match the type of they query operator, there is no match.

Answer (score 1):

I am not getting any issues with the query.

As you are using [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) condition, anyone of one condition should be fallen into true.

I have tried your query, where you are passing `.*22532.*` the value that is neither in `template_id` nor in `user_id`. Hence, you are not getting any data.

**Please try with below query**

**QUERY:**

```
db.getCollection('test1').find(
{ "$or":[
  {"template_id":{"$regex":".*M23.*","$options":"i"}},
  {"user_id":{"$regex":".*23.*","$options":"i"}
 }]
})
```

The result is coming perfectly.

**Results:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ef21b7de21f8756b67da6e7"),
    "action_monkey" : 0,
    "feedback" : false,
    "more_feedback" : 0,
    "template_id" : "M23G5RK",
    "user_id" : 23423
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ee74a95ae8ac276076db26a"),
    "action_monkey" : 0,
    "feedback" : false,
    "more_feedback" : 0,
    "template_id" : "M23G5RK",
    "user_id" : 23375
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ee6c6faae8ac276076db24b"),
    "action_monkey" : 0,
    "feedback" : false,
    "more_feedback" : 0,
    "template_id" : "M23G5RK",
    "user_id" : 23423
}
```

**===== EDIT: =====**

As `user_id` is integer value normal regex filter will not work on an integer value. So, we will convert an integer value to a string to apply the regex filter.

```
db.getCollection('test1').aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
            "user_id_s": { "$toLower": "$user_id" }, 
            "document": "$$ROOT"
        }
     },
     { "$match": {
        "$or":[
            {"document.template_id":{"$regex":".*M23123.*","$options":"i"}},
            {"user_id_s":{"$regex":".*23.*","$options":"i"}}
         ]
     
     }},
    {
        "$replaceRoot": {
            newRoot: "$document"
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: I have one Query which is working absolutely fine on same pattern

Comment: db.dpsExtractedData.find({"$or":[{"product_id":{"$regex":".*60945.*","$options":"i"}},{"style_id":{"$regex":".*60945.*","$options":"i"}}]})

Comment: Please check style_id and user_id type is a string or integer

Comment: I am actually using Lara table package with Laravel to fetch data from MongoDB using jessenger

Comment: I see. I am not aware of the Lara table package and jessenger. Thanks!

Comment: Just for the information again that using this same query template_id is working fine only concern is with user_id column

Comment: I see your above query working but I have a different problem, one of my query is providing me accurate result which is "db.dpsExtractedData.find({"$or":[{"product_id":{"$regex":".*60945.*","$options":"i"}},{"style_id":{"$regex":".*60945.*","$options":"i"}}]})" but the other query is not giving me result which is the one mentioned at top with sample data and both have user_id and product_id as int values

Comment: How on planet EARTH does (1) this answer have a million comments (2) addresses the question directly and (3) works -- and yet has no Up Votes!?? Thank you @HardikShah - awesome answer!